# react context doesn't save authContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt, react-context

EDIT: Just saw that the post was very long so sorry and thanks a lot to whom can help me.

I'm using react as front in a project and I have a problem that I couldn't solve and didn't find anything on the internet.

So the problem is that I'm using jwt for login and when I log in on my page it's like it removes the state by himself, I'll show you:

(by the way I just started so there is no css)

login page: [image]

logged in: [image]

Then if I refresh the page or do anything like click on a button it will come back to the initial state like I never logged in and throw me to the login page because it doesn't see me logged in.

Here is the code:

authProvider.js:

```js
import { createContext, useState } from "react";


const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

    console.log(auth);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

useAuth.js:

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/authProvider";

const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export default useAuth;
```

login.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/';

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.message) {
                    document.querySelector('#error').innerHTML = data.message;
                }
                setAuth({ email, password, token: data.token, refreshToken: data.refreshToken, role: data.role });
                console.log(auth);
                navigate(from, { replace: true });
            });
    }


    return (
        <>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <span id='error'></span>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" required onChange={(e) => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" required onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} />
                <button type='submit'>se connecter</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

the image for the logs:[image]

and nav.js just so you know how I know it works but state doesn't stay:

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const Nav = () => {
    const { auth } = useAuth();
    return (
        <>
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        {
                            !auth ?
                                <>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
                                    </li>
                                </>
                                : null
                        }
                        {
                            auth?.role === 'user' ?
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                                </li>
                                : null
                        }
                        {
                            auth?.role === 'admin' ?
                                <li>
                                    <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
                                </li>
                                : null
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Nav;
```

I don't know if you need more but just say me if needed.

Comment: You don't have any logic to persist state between sessions, your app works as expected. On refresh all state is removed.

Comment: @DennisVash I don't understand, I almost copy paste half of this on youtube and it worked with the guy... how do I persist it then? without exposing the tokens in cookie, because it was all the purpose why i used context

Comment: Context just help you to pass state and variable to all your components. You need to store your state in local storage or in cookies or in session. At some moments you can make a check request to the database to verify token/key.

Comment: @ChooseGoose so I have to store tokens in cookie/localstorage?

Comment: Yes, because context with your state will be refreshed every time you reload the page and user is logged out. So you need to have a function in the context which checks that your local storage (or whatever) contains key.
But in some situations you have to check that this key is valid, for example when the user change a password etc

Comment: ok thanks I'll try to add in localStorage then